# What's too broad about my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-hold

I have a question about my Super User post: [How to protect my files against application? (Sandboxing?)](https://superuser.com/questions/1357286/how-to-protect-my-files-against-application-sandboxing)

First, I'm not complaining, I'm just trying to understand.

Second, I already edited the question in an attempt to comply with the problem. See bellow for more details.

So, my question: what is too broad about [my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1357286/how-to-protect-my-files-against-application-sandboxing)?

The core of the question is "how to deny access to certain files to an application" and *everything else* is supposed to explain it: what exactly I'm trying to solve, in which situations and environment I want to do it, what research I did, etc. - in other words, it's an attempt to make myself clear, not to ask something more. As I wrote, the core itself is "to block file access", nothing more.

I tried to reduce the question as much as possible, but I'm still interested in **what did I wrong**. I don't know whether you have access to edit history of my question (it's the oldest edit), so just in case, I copy the original question here;

**Copy of my original question; it's for reference only and I'm not trying to ask this question in meta:**

> **Short question**
>
> How can I protect my files against different application? By "protect"
>   I mean against access, read, write and execute.
>
> **System**
>
> - Xubuntu 64bit (currently 16.04, want to upgrade to 18.04)
>
> **More elaborated**
>
> Every day, I use lots of applications, both open source and binary
>   blobs - Firefox, Thunderbird, Skype, Unity 3D (game engine, not DE),
>   Dropbox, games, wine (!), and many, many more.
>
> I do trust these applications to do what they advertise and that they
>   don't do something malicious in an obvious way. But I don't trust them
>   *completely*. A bug happens. One untrustworthy person added some backdoor. Anything can happen. And all of these applications have full
>   access to all my files (contacts, KeePass database, photos, ...) and
>   to network.
>
> So if I trust them *partially*, I would like that they have only
>   *partial* access to my data.
>
> **What kind of problem I want to solve?**
>
> I use ssh for deployment of some things. I use keys, because it's
>   *convenient* and many articles claims that this is *safer* than using password. But the key is just stored on disk, just sitting there,
>   *available to every. single. application. and. game. I. use.* Some say the key should be password protected - OK, but what prevents any
>   application to upload it anyway and then someone just brute-force
>   crack it?
>
> So I focused on this - how can I protect the ssh key against any
>   application which doesn't need it?
>
> Later, I realized the problem is much bigger. I wanted to try Discord,
>   but then I found it sets status to indicate *which game I'm playing*.
>   *By default*. As I wrote earlier - I *do* trust the application, but only *partially*.
>
> **What solutions I found so far?**
>
> AppArmor - seems like what I'm looking for. But it works on
>   root/system level, and I couldn't find a way how to use it in user
>   space.
>
> Sandboxing - on first look, it seems - again - like what I'm looking
>   for. Except (almost) all answers to other people asking for this are:
>   "it's unreliable, use virtualization instead".
>
> Virtualization - one, or two applications, OK. But is standard PC able
>   to handle about 10-20 virtual systems? Just running one Windows XP in
>   VirtualBox (I have one piece of HW which is not working in Linux nor
>   newer Windows) takes almost half of resources.
>
> Separate user accounts on PC - it's really inconvenient. It would be
>   nice, for example, to separate into at least "development/work" and
>   "free time" accounts. But it's not much usable for me;
>
> - There are apps which I don't completely trust, but use in both cases (Firefox, Thunderbird, Skype, Discord, Dropbox, ...)
> - Double desktop configuration
> - I also use a laptop and Unison to sync data. This would make syncing two times more of drag.
>
> I actually already use two accounts for a reason. It's already tedious
>   and so I use one of them only marginally. (And I know that I can
>   ctrl+alt+fX to go into different terminal and `startx` to start
>   another desktop session.)
>
> **Last notes**
>
> I'm not naive. I know that any convenient solution (like sandboxing or
>   AppArmor) is not 100% bulletproof. And especially after last year and
>   cases like Spectre, Meltdown, Intel ME, etc. I'm fully aware that it's
>   impossible to secure the PC completely. I know that only way how to
>   protect against directed network attack is to unplug the cable (and
>   with sound-based attacks, even that might not be enough), but my
>   target is *decrease* the risk, not *eliminate*.
>
> I mean, I would like to try new apps from time to time, like Discord,
>   new game, etc. But I would like to keep it somehow separated from my
>   ssh keys, from contact list in Thunderbird, from my photos, etc.

Comment: Reopened after your edit.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I would like to ask - will you find some time for me to explain, what I'm doing wrong? I would like to understand, but, of course, I don't want to bother you too much. Or should I just leave?

Comment: Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Last question: what if I read that _before asking_ and all parts (except the last one - 'last notes') of original question were carefully written (and many times rewritten) with these rules in mind? (The last part - 'last notes' - was meant as defense against answers like "nothing is 100% safe".)

Comment: @DavidPostill I guess there is nothing else you can or want to do to help me. In that case, thank you for your support until now, I really appreciate it. Regrettably it seems like I'm unable to understand and/or correctly apply local rules, so I just wanted to thank for you guidance.